# Python LXML parse error on Evernote XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml, evernote

I'm trying to parse [Evernote Markup Language](http://dev.evernote.com/start/core/enml.php) (ENML) with lxml in Python 2.7.  ENML is a superset of XHTML.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import lxml.etree as etree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml_str = StringIO('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">\r\n\r\n<en-note style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;">\nA really simple example. &nbsp;Another sentence.\n</en-note>')
    tree = etree.parse(xml_str)
```

The code above errors out with:

```
XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'nbsp' not defined, line 5, column 32
```

How do I successfully parse ENML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is understood by the HTML parser, not the XML parser:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import lxml.html as LH
if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml_str = StringIO('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">\r\n\r\n<en-note style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;">\nA really simple example. &nbsp;Another sentence.\n</en-note>')
    tree = LH.parse(xml_str)
    print(LH.tostring(tree))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing the entity names by their numerical values.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Comment: or, better, by an appropriately encoded unicode character